# Merge Excel Files Into One

Tags: .net, excel

I have a few hundred Excel files, where each file has some data on the first sheet. I've been asked to write a console application in C# which merges all of the Excel files together into a single document while retaining the formatting.

The consolidated file is a single workbook containing a sheet for each file merged into the document. Unfortunately, the Excel files are in binary rather than XML format, so I can't perform an XSL transformation.

**Is there are free library or sample code which demonstrates how to combine a sheets from multiple Excel documents into a single file?**

Comment: Are you looking for an Excel based or a stand-alone (third-party) solution?

Comment: try this tool - JMC Excel
http://jeeshenlee.wordpress.com/2010/09/23/jmc-excel-join-merge-combine-multiple-excel-sheets-or-excel-workbooks/

Comment: @JeeShenLee the link you shared is no longer available, Update is required!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the Microsoft Excel Interop library. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.aspx

You should be able to add a reference, in the com tab, to Microsoft Excel 11 Object Library.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Hopefully all of your excel files are the same version.

Answer (score 2):

This is an easy task for a neat little program called Bulk File Merger (they have a Mac version called Excel File Merger).  I managed to merge over 300 files in a matter of minutes.  You can also merge csv files, which takes even less time.  We banged out over 1300 csv files in seconds.  Scary.

Answer (score 1):

It's not free (a developer license is $ 425) but [GemBox](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/) has a very good library that is way faster than using the office objects. We use it in my current project since a year and a half, and it has consistently performed very well for us.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO).
You can open workbooks in code and use a lot of the excel functionality, as well as copying worksheets like you've said you need to do.

For resources, [this MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/b31bf687-2549-436a-8997-c11c9f3258ed/) demonstrates opening excel files and copying worksheets.  Hopefully this will get you on the right direction.

Answer (score -3):

Of course you can do Tool->Compare->Merge Workbooks.  And within Excel as Joshua mentioned there is the merge method in the COM Interop libraries. If you need some help let me know I work heavily in Excel and may be able to help you out on a small fee basis.

Comment: - for touting business