# How to put three Excel worksheets under one workbook

Tags: c#, excel, com-interop, worksheet

I have three Excel worksheets which I want to merge under a single workbook.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do this in C#, have a look at [Merge Excel Files Into One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830841/merge-excel-files-into-one) for some ideas.

You will need the Microsoft Excel Interop library.  I found the following example at http://forums.asp.net/p/1457463/3498328.aspx

```
ApplicationClass excelApplicationClass = new ApplicationClass();
_Workbook finalWorkbook = null;
Workbook workBook = null;
Worksheet workSheet = null;
Worksheet newWorksheet = null;

// Open or create destination WorkBook
finalWorkbook = excelApplicationClass.Workbooks.Open("dest.xlsx", ...);

//Open the source WorkBook
workBook = excelApplicationClass.Workbooks.Open("src.xlsx", ...);

//Open the WorkSheet
workSheet = (Worksheet)workBook.Sheets[1];

int countWorkSheet = finalWorkbook.Worksheets.Count;

newWorksheet = (Worksheet)finalWorkbook.Sheets[countWorkSheet];
workSheet.Copy(Missing.Value, newWorksheet);   //Copy from src to destn

finalWorkbook.Save();
workBook.Save();
```

Do a search for the Excel.Workseet.Copy() method.  This should get you going down the needed code path.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open all of the workbooks at once
2. Then right-click on the name of the first sheet you wish to copy and choose `Move or Copy...`
3. In the `To book` drop-down select the book you wish to copy to
4. Tick the box that says `Create a copy`
5. Press `OK`
6. Repeat steps 2-5 for the other 2 sheets

Comment: i wanted  to  write an program  for this in c#. i do not want  to  do it  manually.